# Can't make different API versions have different Swagger documentation URLs

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a single API that I want to divide in "versions". They're not really versions per se, they're more like subsets of the same API with different methods that I want to expose to different clients. Although they're using the same API, I don't want to document methods of version A to clients of version B and viceversa.

So far, using swagger versioning and a custom attribute I've been able to effectively separate the two "versions" of my API, and I've used EnableDiscoveryUrlSelector() to populate a dropdown so I can change versions and explore all of them inside my custom index.html.

But that's not exactly what I want. What I want is to type http://server/api-help/ApiSubsetX/index.html and get the swagger documentation for ApiSubsetX and ONLY that, or use http://server/api-help/ApiSubsetY/index.html to get the documentation for ApiSubsetY.

If I browse to http://server/api-docs/ApiSubsetX I get the json for ApiSubsetX, can I use that? Any ideas?

I know the question is a bit generic, but the problem is that I don't know how to do it, not that something is failing in my implementation. Any help or pointer is welcome. Thanks.

EDIT: I'm not using ApiVersioning.